# How to handle when the BROKER rabbitMq is down in Spring cloud stream?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-cloud-stream

I want to understand how can we handle a situation where the broker itself is down in my case this is RabbitMQ,also i don't want to try the **RETRY mechanism**.Rather i would like to check in spring cloud stream,**how can it be detected whether RabbitMQ is down or not** and depending on this condition i need to push the messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@AutoWired
private CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
```

Call `connectionFactory.createConnection().close()` to verify that the broker is up. If it's not you'll catch an exception.

In general, this won't open a new connection, it will just check that the shared (or a cached) connection is available.

Comment: can i use Spring cloud stream send method in try catch block this way.

---
try{
   source.normalUser().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(user).build());
}
----

if it catches exception,then the connection is down.

Comment: Perfect..Thanks Gary.